# Using PySerial is it possible to wait for data?

Tags: python, serial-port, pyserial

I've got a Python program which is reading data from a serial port via the **PySerial** module. The two conditions I need to keep in mind are: I don't know how much data will arrive, and I don't know when to expect data.

Based on this I have came up with the follow code snippets:

```
#Code from main loop, spawning thread and waiting for data
s = serial.Serial(5, timeout=5)  # Open COM5, 5 second timeout
s.baudrate = 19200

#Code from thread reading serial data
while 1:
  tdata = s.read(500)    # Read 500 characters or 5 seconds

  if(tdata.__len__() > 0):        #If we got data
    if(self.flag_got_data is 0):  #If it's the first data we recieved, store it
      self.data = tdata        
    else:                         #if it's not the first, append the data
      self.data += tdata
      self.flag_got_data = 1
```

So this code will loop forever getting data off the serial port. We'll get up to 500 characters store the data, then alert the main loop by setting a flag. If no data is present we'll just go back to sleep and wait.

The code is working, but I don't like the 5s timeout. I need it because I don't know how much data to expect, but I don't like that it's waking up every 5 seconds even when no data is present.

Is there any way to check when data becomes available before doing the `read`? I'm thinking something like the `select` command in Linux.

**Note:** I found the `inWaiting()` method, but really that seems it just change my "sleep" to a poll, so that's not what I want here. I just want to sleep until data comes in, then go get it.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Ok, I actually got something together that I like for this. Using a combination of `read()` with no timeout and the `inWaiting()` method:

```
#Modified code from main loop: 
s = serial.Serial(5)

#Modified code from thread reading the serial port
while 1:
  tdata = s.read()           # Wait forever for anything
  time.sleep(1)              # Sleep (or inWaiting() doesn't give the correct value)
  data_left = s.inWaiting()  # Get the number of characters ready to be read
  tdata += s.read(data_left) # Do the read and combine it with the first character

  ... #Rest of the code
```

This seems to give the results I wanted, I guess this type of functionality doesn't exist as a single method in Python

Comment: `time.sleep(1)` seems like a pretty ugly hack that adds a bunch of delay to getting your data out.

Comment: @TJD - No argument there, seems it works without the sleep as well, but the `data_left` becomes very unreliable (a string of 19 characters loops as 3, then 10, then 6 "banks" came in). So I'm still not happy with it, but it's closer to what I was thinking about. Sleep until data, then read data, then go back to sleep.

Comment: I don't see how that is "unreliable".  That's exactly how the bytes are arriving as you are reading them.  You might want to use `interCharTimeout`, which lets you detect when the receiver has stopped seeing any new bytes.

Answer (score 14):

You can set `timeout = None`, then the `read` call will block until the requested number of bytes are there.  If you want to wait until data arrives, just do a `read(1)` with timeout `None`.  If you want to check data without blocking, do a `read(1)` with timeout zero, and check if it returns any data.

(see documentation https://pyserial.readthedocs.io/en/latest/)

Comment: But I also think there is absolutely nothing wrong with using a 5s timeout and having it wakeup and immediately go back to read.  It's very simple and will have no measurable overhead.

Comment: Thanks for the info, I did see the read documentation just couldn't figure out how to make it do what I wanted. I agree having a loop with a timeout isn't terribly costly on a desktop machine, but (coming from an embedded background) it feels so wrong to me to poll

Comment: Better solution in my opinion (at least for my needs). Thanks for sharing.

Answer (score 2):

```
def cmd(cmd,serial):
    out='';prev='101001011'
    serial.flushInput();serial.flushOutput()
    serial.write(cmd+'\r');
    while True:
        out+= str(serial.read(1))
        if prev == out: return out
        prev=out
    return out
```

call it like this:

```
cmd('ATZ',serial.Serial('/dev/ttyUSB0', timeout=1, baudrate=115000))
```